# VSCode: change a word using regex

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change all words that finish by `_was` to `_before_last_save`

Regex: `\b((\w+))_was`
Replace: `$0_before_last_save`

The problem is that it changes `user_was` by `user_was_before_last_save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the combination you want:

Regexp: `\b(\w+)_was`

Replace: `$1_before_last_save`

Even though this is not yet "all words that finish by _was"
but alla words concat to _was and potentially something else

this will match also

anything_was**Anythingelse** --> anything_before_last_save**Anythingelse**

this probably would be a better fit:

Regexp: `\b(\w+)_was\b`